# How to search nested property in Hibernate Criteria

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-criteria

My entity User has a nested property (in Oracle, it maps to a string field format as JSON) like the following snippet:

```
@Entity(name = "users")

public class User extends Auditable implements Serializable {

   private Long id;

   private String username;

   private String password;

   @Convert(converter = UserInformationConverter.class)
   private UserInfomation additionalInformation;
}

public class UserInfomation {
   private String email;

   private String phoneNumber;
}
```

And then, I would like to search by the "email" property in the "additionalInformation" field in Criteria query. I tried:

```
predicate = cb.and(predicate, cb.like(root.get("additionalInformation").get("email"), cb.parameter(String.class, "email")));
```

But I got the error:

```
"Illegal attempt to dereference path source [null.additionalInformation] of basic type; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal attempt to dereference path source [null.additionalInformation] of basic type"
```

Please suggest me some solutions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the criteriaBuilder like:

```
 cb.like(cb.lower(root.get("additionalInformation").get("email"));
```